# How can i update another model fields when i save another form

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates

Hi i have 2 models `Game` and `Match`

models.py

```
class Game(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    team1score = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True,default=0)
    ...
    team2score = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True,default=0)
    ...



class Match(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    game=models.ForeignKey(Game,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    team1score = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True,default=0)
    ...
    team2score = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True,default=0)
    ...
```

forms.py

```
class MatchForm(forms.ModelForm):
    team1score = forms.IntegerField(widget=forms.TextInput,required=False)
    team2score = forms.IntegerField(widget=forms.TextInput,required=False)


    class Meta:
        model=Match
        fields=['team1score',
                'team2score',
                ...
                ]
```

I'm creating a match object with the code below.

views.py

```
def creatematch(request,...):
     form = MatchForm(request.POST or None)

        if form.is_valid():
            match = form.save(commit=False)
            ...

            match.save()
            ...
```

Now, my question is how can i update `game.team1score` and `game.team2score`
when i create `match` objects

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `ForeignKey` relation of your `Match` model to get the `Game` instance you want:

```
def creatematch(request,...):
     form = MatchForm(request.POST or None)

        if form.is_valid():
            match = form.save(commit=False)[0]
            game = match.game 
            game.team1score += match.team1score
            game.team2score += match.team2score
            game.save()
            match.save()
```

But this is a sub-optimal solution because you actually run a `SELECT * FROM GAME`, wait for the result, then perform the calculation all before sending a second query to your Database.

Instead you should use [`F()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/expressions/#f-expressions), which does this calculation at your database:

```
from django.db.models import F

def creatematch(request,...):
     form = MatchForm(request.POST or None)

        if form.is_valid():
            match = form.save(commit=False)[0]
            game = match.game 
            game.team1score = F('team1score') + match.team1score
            game.team2score = F('team2score') + match.team2score

            game.save()
            match.save()
```